# Can't add child sprite on scaled object

Tags: sprite, cocos2d-x, scale, cocos2d-x-3.0, addchild

Ok, guys, here's the deal.

```
aboutBackground = Sprite::create("fadeBack.png");
aboutBackground->setScale(winSize.width, winSize.height);
aboutBackground->setPosition(winSize.width*0.5, winSize.height*0.5);
this->addChild(aboutBackground);

Sprite *sprAboutPanel = Sprite::create("aboutPanel.png");
sprAboutPanel->setPosition(aboutBackground->getBoundingBox().size.width*0.5, aboutBackground->getBoundingBox().size.height*0.5);
aboutBackground->addChild(sprAboutPanel);
```

Before scaling `aboutBackground` sprite it works perfectly. But because `aboutBackground` is just a fading background, I decided to go with `1px` picture and scale it to full screen. But right now `sprAboutPanel` doesn't appear on the screen. I really wonder why? Thx for your responses!

Comment: You know `sprAboutPanel` positioning will be relative to `aboutBackground`'s position ? Try to scale `aboutBackground` half of `winsize` and feedback your observations.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use in this instance is to not add the about panel as a child of the background, but rather the scene instead. Scaling a parent makes for tricky positioning of children since positions are scaled. You would probably find that in your code if you set the position of aboutPanel to (0.5,0.5) it would probably work as expected.

I would instead change:

```
aboutBackground->addChild(sprAboutPanel);
```

to this:

```
this->addChild(sprAboutPanel);
```